# AngularJS disable input type button If other fields are not completed

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a poll and would like to disable the input type button until you have selected a radio button from the poll options. This is what I have so far...

```
<div class="options" ng-hide="$root.offline">
        <div class="overlay overlay--loading" ng-show="poll.loading"></div>
        <div class="option" ng-repeat="option in poll.options">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.response" name="poll-{{poll.ID}}" value="{{ option.option }}">
                <span class="radiobtn" ng-hide="poll.answered"></span>
                <span compile="option.option"></span>
            </label>
            <div class="result" ng-show="poll.answered">
                <div class="result-bar">
                    <div ng-attr-style="{{'width: '+ option.percentage +'%;'}}"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="result-percentage">{{ option.percentage ? option.percentage : 0 }}%</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Vote" ng-hide="poll.answered || $root.offline" ng-click="vote()" ng-disabled="!$parent.response" />
    </div>
```

This disables the button but when I select an option it's stil disabled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it. Can't call parent outside the loop.

```
<input type="button" value="Vote" ng-hide="poll.answered || $root.offline" ng-click="vote()" ng-disabled="!response" />
```